# Ionic 3 with Stripe plugin

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, stripe-payments, ionic3

According to the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/stripe/) this plugin supports 'Browser', but 
page hangs when get injected Stripe:

1. installed @ionic-native/stripe
2. imported

> import { Stripe } from '@ionic-native/stripe';

3. injected in constructor

> constructor(private stripe: Stripe) {}

After actions above my page is not loading (and no error in console) via 'ionic serve'

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this through `ionic-native/stripe`. It is a wrapper of native Cordova plugin. So you must use the device for testing.

Stripe doc says about the javascript API without a native plugin. It is working fine on web apps since no Cordova there.

Need to use this CLI:

```
ionic cordova run android --prod --device
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `browser` platform before using it in the browser:

```
 ionic cordova platform add browser
```

And the to run it:

```
 ionic cordova platform run browser
```

It will not work with `ionic-serve` because then only the content of your `www` folder is served and all of cordova is missing.